# How can I extract key from object?

Tags: arrays, json

I want to extract genres key from **movie api json.** and filtered by what I clicked button (i.e. drama, documentary... etc)

But the genres so complicated to extract because it has array

```
 [{id:1, genres:['drama']},{id:2, genres:['action, war']},{id:3, genres:['drama','documentary','sci-fi']},{id:4, genres :["crime","drama","romance"]} ..etc ]
```

I just want to extract only one genres factor (i.e drama, action, drama, crime... ) and when the button clicked, the filtered movie show on the screen.
Can you give me a tips?

```js
function setEventListenrs(movies) {
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
const btn = document.querySelector('.icron');
logo.addEventListener('click', displayMovie(movies));
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => onButtonClick(event, movies));
}

function onButtonClick(event, movies) {
const dataset = event.target.dataset;
const key = dataset.key; //genre
const value = dataset.value; //comedy 
      
      //1) tried to make the new array to extract one factor of genres 
const arr = new Array();
movies.forEach((movie) => arr.push(movie.genres[0]));
console.log(arr);
if (arr.includes(value)) {
console.log(movies.genres[0]); 

//even I assigned new key & value to make the new array.  

    let key="ge";
    const arr3 = new Array(); 

    for(let i=0; i<movies.length; i++){
        let arr2 ={[key]:arr[i]};
        arr3.push(arr2);
}
        console.log(arr3); 
//[{ge: ['comic']},{ge; ['drama', 'action']} ... ]
   
      
      // 2) I tried to using the fillter() api. 
//but console show this message 
//"TypeError: movieG.filter is not a function"

      
for (const value of it) {
let movieG = value.genres[0];
const filtered = movieG.filter((movie) => movie[key] === value);
console.log(filtered);
if (value == movieG) {
console.log(movies.filter((movie) => movie[key]));
        }
console.log(value.genres[0]);
      }


      
function displayMovie(movies) {
const container = document.querySelector('.mList');
container.innerHTML = movies.map((movie) => createHTMLString(movie)).join('');
}
```

```html
  <button class="btn" data-key="genres" data-value="Comedy">Comedy</button>
        <button class="btn" data-key="genres" data-value="Action">Action</button>
        <button class="btn" data-key="genres" data-value="Drama">Drama</button>
```

Comment: Your code has unbalanced braces. And is it intended that the genre for the second movie has the two genres in one string? There are several undefined variables in your code, like `it`??

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
let apiList = [{id:1, genres:['drama']},
               {id:2, genres:['action, war']},
               {id:3, genres:['drama','documentary','sci-fi']},
               {id:4, genres :["crime","drama","romance"]}]

apiList.forEach(element => console.log(Object.values(element)[1][0]));
//Will result the first value of every array:
//drama
//action, war
//drama
//crime
```

keep in mind at id:2 is missing a correct key assignment. It should be `{id:2, genres:['action', 'war']},`

After that you can perform any logic with your resulting genres...

I hope that helps to pin point your case.